# Specify Which Types For NSwag to Build

Tags: nswag

I'm using NSwag to generate a TypeScript file at buildtime as described [here](https://blog.sanderaernouts.com/autogenerate-typescript-api-client-with-nswag).

This is using the `nswag.msbuild` package with these key lines in the csproj file.

```
  <Target Name="NSwag" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition="'$(GenerateCode)'=='True' ">
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Core30) run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
  </Target>
```

My issue is that it is only generating TypeScript files for types which are included as either input or output parameters in controller action methods. We have an architectural requirement to generate TypeScript for other classes which are not consumed by the API. Is there a way to tell NSwag to do this? Perhaps include all classes in an assembly with a specific attribute?

Thanks.

Comment: Answer was posted on github - https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/3034   - "You can implement and add a custom document processor, in the process method you can retrieve the schema generator and add more types"